# How can I run a Django function on a button press which doesn't render content?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I'm getting on quite well with Django & Python, just got a search function working. But I'm unsure of my next problem.

I've got a function that connects to Amazon S3 and stores keys in my database. I currently run this when a page renders, but what I want is to have a button which runs this call so it'll be like a refresh button to update the database with the latest content.

The action on search goes to `/search/` so urls takes care of giving that a template and a view to run the search code. But if my update form has action="." and should change the page, how do you point it to the function? (I'm using generic views)

It'd probably be a good idea to render results from the function to the screen, but I first just want to understand how you call a function that doesn't necessarily show the user anything.

My function is fairly simple (and yes, I've added that first if statement as I try to implement this):

```
def updateRevFromS3(request):
    if ('r' in request.POST) and request.POST['r'].stript():
        s3 = boto.connect_s3(
            settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)  # Connect to Amazon S3
        b = s3.get_bucket(
            settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)  # Find existing bucket to store data
        revision = b.list(prefix="{{ update_revision }}")

        for key in revision:
            # download values to db
            try:
                obj = screenshots.objects.get(imgUrl=key.name,
                                              mod_date=key.last_modified)
            except screenshots.DoesNotExist:
                obj = screenshots(imgUrl=key.name,
                                  meta=key.metadata,
                                  mod_date=key.last_modified)
                obj.save()
                print "Saving: " + key.name
            else:
                print key.name + " already exists."
```

And my form:

```
<form action="." method="get" id="updateForm">{% csrf_token %}
   <label>Update images for revision:</label><br/>
   <input type="text" name="r" value="{{ update_revision|escape }}"/> 
   <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

The next step would be to give the user some feedback as a result, but I'll get on to that after I can call the function! Thanks :)

**update**

I've put some jQ in to catch the update form (I put an alert in to test this);

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#updateForm").bind("submit", function () {
        $.post(ajax_url, {r: $(this).find('[name="r"]').val()}, function (data) {
            // nothing here for now, but this is where you could update the UI, etc. 
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

And my default view is as follows (this always falls through the final return);

```
def index(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        print "is ajax"
        return updateRevFromS3(request)
    elif request.POST.get('r') == "updateForm":
        print "is post"
        return updateRevFromS3(request)
    print "not ajax or post"
    return render_to_response("base.html", RequestContext(request))
```

Seen as though I've not idea what I'm really doing with this, I'm not sure why my console window shows GET and POST requests on each page load. If thats the case why doesn't the index view return `updateRevFromS3()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a normal form POST, the page will reload - that's just how HTTP works. To have a 'background' POST, you need to use AJAX. If you have jQuery on your page, you'll want to add an ID to your form so it can be easily selected, then do something like this:

```js
$("#formid").bind("submit", function(){
    $.post(ajax_url, {r: $(this).find('[name="r"]').val()}, function(data){
        // nothing here for now, but this is where you could update the UI, etc.
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here are the [relevant jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

In your view, you can conditionally dispatch to the refreshing function based on `request.is_ajax()` (or any other condition, say, whether a particular POST key provided by a hidden input is present):

```python
def your_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax(): return updateRevFromS3(request)
    elif request.POST.get("my-hidden-input-name") == "this-is-the-update-form":
        return updateRevFromS3(request)
    return normal_processing()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code :) I thought I'd have to throw jQuery at it but was just trying to get the function called before I worried about that.

Comment: Gotcha. You could just check for `request.method == "POST"`, unless the first page is also loaded via post. Other options are a hidden input so you can detect that it's the refresh form, or checking `request.is_ajax()` if you jump right to the jquery version. I've updated my answer with a couple examples.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid using a view for it because I've got generic views showing all the items in my database and then a sidebar which currently has the search in and thats where I wanted to run this update function from. So it's that running a function that isn't available in a view that I've not yet figured out

Comment: Right, if you're using generic views, you're going to have to find the appropriate hooks (or not use a generic view, if it's not possible) to call your `updateRevFromS3`. Please add the view code where the form currently POSTs to your question if you're having trouble with that, so we can see where to add the checks.

Comment: Right, I've updated my question. Still a little lost as to why the view doesn't get the ajax or the post. Thanks though :)

Comment: `request.POST.get('r')` wouldn't be `"updateForm"`, it would be the value of the `{{ update_revision|safe }}` template expression. Try, instead, adding a hidden input to the form, with a *different* name and value of `updateForm`, then use `request.POST.get('the_name') == 'updateForm'` to detect the refresh POST. `request.is_ajax()` would only be working if you had integrated jquery per the first code sample in my answer.

Comment: Oh, just saw you did. When you said you added an alert to test it, did it work? And did also add `id="updateForm"` to the form?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8969/discussion-between-marksweb-and-adamkg)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a page reload, the easiest way to do this is by having some JavaScript that performs the HTTP request for you. Take a look at [jquery](http://jquery.com/), it's a JS library that makes things like this a breeze.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I'd have to throw jQuery at it but was just trying to get the function called before I worried about that.